# Angular Google Maps - WeatherLayer: celsius to fahrenheit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I am new to Angular and have been playing around with the Angular google-maps and their example in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/KmREW0ANYT8C2LM8dH9l?p=preview . Applying the weather layer to the map, I am trying to change celsius to fahrenheit.

I figured I could change the option this way, in the options scope:

```
angular.module('appMaps', ['google-maps'.ns()])
.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.map = {center: {latitude: 51.219053, longitude: 4.404418 }, zoom: 4 };
    $scope.options = {scrollwheel: false, temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT};
    $scope.showWeather = true;
});
```

That did not work. Where should I apply that option? Thanks

Comment: can you share the plunker link

Comment: @HarishR [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/KmREW0ANYT8C2LM8dH9l?p=preview)